# Best way to ignore less specific click event with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the code below. The main code is in the 2nd function however the first is called which is interfering with the more specific a.One code.

Whats the best way to not run code in the first function if the div i click is a .main .a.One event?

```
$('.main .a').live('click', function () {
    alert('first');
    //2 lines of code
});
$('.main .a.One').live('click', function () {
    alert('second');
    //lots of logic
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.main .a').live('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('One'))
    {
        alert('first');
        //2 lines of code
        return;
    }

    alert('second');
    //lots of logic
});
```